# configurable product price not changing

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, frontend

I have created a configurable product "bag" with the color attribute.
color:blue,red.

[image]
 i missed out to add the price while creating the product itself.

So the front end price not changing while i change the colors in option.

[image]

Please anyone help me to solve it by codes..

Comment: Have you added the price and re-indexed catalog and clear the cache?

Comment: i want to add more the 1500 products. i thought to write a automation script to add the price.

Comment: You can add the products via custom script or import and then run re-index for flat catalog and prices I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php

class Websanity_Cataloginventory_Adminhtml_StockController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{
    /* 
     * initial layout
    */
    private function _init(){
        return $this->loadLayout();
    }

    /* 
     *
    */
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->_init();
        $this->renderLayout();

    }
    public $productIdsExcel = array();  
    public $productsExcel = array();
    public $updatedSku = array();
    public $unUpdatedSku = array();

    /* 
     *  Import product with csv file
    */
    public function importCatalogInventoryAction(){

        try
        {       
            $path = Mage::getBaseDir() . DS . 'var' . DS . 'websanity' . DS . 'tmp' . DS ;  //desitnation directory     
            $fname = $_FILES['stockfile']['name'];

            $arrayData = array();
            $file_path= $path . $fname;
            $arrayData = $this->excelToArray($file_path);

            foreach($arrayData as $row)
            {
                $productSku = $row["sku"];
                $attribute = $row["attribute"];
                $attributeValue = $row['attribute_value'];
                $price = $row['attribute_price'];

                $attributeId = $this->getAttributeId($attribute);   

                $productId = $this->getProductId($productSku);

                //Product-id collection from excel

                $this->productIdsExcel[] = $productId;

                //Price for each product and it attrivbutevalues collection from excel

                $this->productsExcel[$productId][$attribute][$attributeValue] = $price;


                $optionId = $this->attributeOption($attributeId, $attributeValue);


                $superAttrbuteId = $this->getSuperAttributeId($productId, $attributeId);

                $addPrices = $this->addPrices($superAttrbuteId, $optionId, $price);

            }


            $this->productIdsExcel = array_unique($this->productIdsExcel);
            $productIds = $this->productIdsExcel;

            foreach($productIds as $pid){

                $_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($pid);
                $prod = $this->getAssociatedProducts($_product);

                foreach($prod as $simpleprod)
                {

                    if($simpleprod->getData('LIGHTSPEED_PRODUCT_SIZE'))
                    {
                        $sizeId = $simpleprod->getData('LIGHTSPEED_PRODUCT_SIZE');
                        $sizeAttributeValues = $this->getAttributeValues($sizeId);
                        foreach($sizeAttributeValues as $size){
                            $sizeValue = $size['value'];
                        }
                        $sizeAddtional = $this->productsExcel[$pid]['size'][$sizeValue];
                        $updatedSku[] = $simpleprod->getSku() ."- Size";
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        $unUpdatedSku[] = $simpleprod->getSku() ."- Size";
                    }

                    if($simpleprod->getData('LIGHTSPEED_PRODUCT_COLOR'))
                    {
                        $colorId =$simpleprod->getData('LIGHTSPEED_PRODUCT_COLOR');
                        $colorAttributeValues = $this->getAttributeValues($colorId);
                        foreach($colorAttributeValues as $color){
                            $colorValue = $color['value'];
                        }
                        $colorAddtional = $this->productsExcel[$pid]['color'][$colorValue];
                            $updatedSku[] = $simpleprod->getSku() ."- Color";
                    }

                    else
                    { 
                        $unUpdatedSku[] = $simpleprod->getSku() ."- Color";
                    }

                    $base = $_product->getPrice();
                    $basePriceAddition = $base + $colorAddtional + $sizeAddtional;
                    $simpleProductPrice = $simpleprod->setPrice($basePriceAddition)->save();

                }
            }
            $update = "";
            $update .= "<h2>Records Updated</h2>";
            foreach($updatedSku as $updated)
            {
                $update .= $updated ."<br/>";

            }

            $update .= "<h2>Records Not Updated</h2>";
            foreach($unUpdatedSku as $unUpdated)
            {
                $update .= $unUpdated ."<br/>";

            }
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setMyValue($update);
            $this->_redirectUrl( Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('*/adminhtml_stock/') );
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
            {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError( $e->getMessage() );
            }
    }


    public function getAssociatedProducts($productId)
    {
        try{
            $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($productId);
            $prod = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
                return $prod;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


    public function getAttributeValues($attributeId)
    {
        try{
            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
            $table = $resource->getTableName('eav/attribute_option');
            $query = 'SELECT value FROM xyzeav_attribute_option_value WHERE option_id=' .$attributeId;

            $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
            return $results;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();

        }
    }




    public function excelToArray($file_path)
    {
        try{
            chmod($file_path,0777);
            error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
            require_once Mage::getBaseDir().'/excel_reader2.php';

            $excel_reader = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
            $excel_reader->setUTFEncoder('iconv');
            $excel_reader->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
            $file=$excel_reader->read($file_path,"UTF-16");
            $file_row=2;
            $column_count=$excel_reader->sheets[0]['numCols'];
            $row_count=$excel_reader->sheets[0]['numRows'];     
            $excelData = array();
            for($file_row;$file_row<=$excel_reader->sheets[0]['numRows'];$file_row++) 
            {   

                $excelData[$file_row]["sku"] = $excel_reader->sheets[0]['cells'][$file_row][1];
                $excelData[$file_row]["attribute"] = $excel_reader->sheets[0]['cells'][$file_row][2];
                $excelData[$file_row]["attribute_value"] = $excel_reader->sheets[0]['cells'][$file_row][3];
                $excelData[$file_row]["attribute_price"] = $excel_reader->sheets[0]['cells'][$file_row][4];
                if($excelData == "")
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
            return $excelData;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


    public function attributeOption($attributeId, $color)
    {
        try{
            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
            $table = $resource->getTableName('eav/attribute_option');

            $query = 'SELECT option_id FROM xyzeav_attribute_option_value WHERE value="'.$color.'" AND option_id in (SELECT option_id FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE attribute_id = '
            . (int)$attributeId.')';

            $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
            return $results[0]['option_id'];
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


    public function getSuperAttributeId($productId, $attr1)
    {
        try{
            $getSuperAttributeId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_attribute')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productId)
            ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_id', $attr1)->getData();

            return  $getSuperAttributeId[0]['product_super_attribute_id'];                 
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }


    public function addPrices($superAttrbuteId, $optionId, $price)
    {
        try{
            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
            $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

            $query = 'SELECT * FROM xyzcatalog_product_super_attribute_pricing WHERE product_super_attribute_id='.$superAttrbuteId.' AND value_index='.$optionId;
            $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

            $getExistingPrice = $results[0]['value_id'];

            if(!$getExistingPrice)
            {
                $insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO xyzcatalog_product_super_attribute_pricing (product_super_attribute_id, value_index, is_percent, pricing_value, website_id) VALUES('.$superAttrbuteId.','.$optionId.',"0",'.$price.',"0")';
                $QueryValue = $writeConnection->query($insertQuery);
                if(!$QueryValue)
                {
                    $result = "Mismatch Values";
                }
                else
                {
                    $result = "Inserted";
                }
            }
            else{

                $new_query = 'UPDATE xyzcatalog_product_super_attribute_pricing SET pricing_value='.$price.' WHERE product_super_attribute_id='.$superAttrbuteId.' AND value_index='.$optionId;
                $QueryValue = $writeConnection->query($new_query);

                if($QueryValue)
                {
                    $result = "Mismatch Values";
                }
                else
                {
                    $result = "Updated";
                }
            }
            return $result;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage(addPrices,'Mismatch Values');
        }
    }

    function printError($fromFunction, $message){
        echo "<hr />";
            echo $fromFunction;
            echo $message;
        echo "<hr />";
    }

    public function getProductId($productSku)
    {
        try{
            $productId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('type_id', 'configurable')                           
            ->addFieldToFilter('sku', $productSku)->getFirstItem()->getId();
                return $productId;

        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


    public function getAttributeId($attribute)
    {
        try{
            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
            $superQuery ='select b.attribute_id from xyzcatalog_product_super_attribute_label a inner join xyzcatalog_product_super_attribute b on a.product_super_attribute_id  = b.product_super_attribute_id where a.value ="'.$attribute.'"' ;

            $superAttribute = $readConnection->fetchAll($superQuery);
            foreach($superAttribute as $super)
            {
                $superId=$super['attribute_id'];
            }
            return $superId;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


    public function getParentProductId()
    {
        try{
            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
            $childQuery = 'select product_id from xyzcatalog_category_product_index  where is_parent = 1';
            $childResults = $readConnection->fetchAll($childQuery);
                return $childResults;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}           

?>
```

- **I have tried this code in my custom module. i uploaded the data's through Excel sku,attribute,label,price.**
- I have used the excel reader to retrieve the values

Answer (score 2):

core magento doesn't support getting the prices for the different configuration from the simple products, instead you have to configure it while adding the associated products in the config product.

There are a few extension which do this, what you expects, e.g. [Simple Configurable Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html), but be careful, sounds like it is no longer maintaned...

Comment: i have try the above code to add the price for the associated products