# Changing price is not reflecting for configurable products

Tags: configurable-product, price, associate-products

i am trying to change the price of associated products .

In the below image, you can see **2 tables**, in first table you can see "**option 3, option 4, option 5**....etc" , next to that column there is a price column . if i edit price there, than its working fine.

There is Price column is 2nd table also. but when i change the Price there, **its not reflecting in frontend**. but quantity is reflecting from 2nd table.

Is Magento works like this only or is there any way so that if i edit price column in 2nd table than also it should work as like 1st table.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how Magento works with configurable products. You set the price to the configurable product itself and the price you set in the first table (with option 3,4,5,etc.) is added to that price. Magento skips the price of the simple products.

To make it look to the price of the simple products, you'll need customisations in your Magento code (an extension).

Comment: can you please help me finding an good extension for this or what code i need to change to work this price for simple products.

Comment: Customising it yourself isn't that easy, since you need to change a lot of stuff. Also, because a price is only available when all options are set. I did a quick search on extensions, but I have no idea which is a good one, since I never used an extension for this.

Comment: is this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30146/configurable-product-price-not-changing work for me , if so can you please give other files of modules

Comment: That's a different question. This might be a solution to your question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19108/magento-configurable-product-price-overriding-simple-product-price

Comment: i am checking that link and update you soon.

Comment: Unfortunately it did't worked for me. i used @Alan answer there and did reindex

Comment: Did you try the github solution that's in there? I know people that used that extension and were pretty happy with it.

Comment: http://hotwheelstoys.in/upload/em0113-full-package/index.php/anashria-womens-premier-leather-sandal.html sorry, it worked for me in cart page but not in product view page. please help me for this.

Comment: is that github solution will work for product view page or only for cart page ?

Comment: You can read that on the github page. Just give it a try.

Comment: sure, i am trying now.

Comment: when i used only git hub extension, than it worked only in view page. than i override the price.php using  @alan answer , than Fatal error: Call to a member function getFinalPrice() on a non-object in /home/outthinking/public_html/upload/em0113-full-package/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php on line 717 now its giving

Comment: please check here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100433/how-to-over-ride-the-extension-code

Comment: If it worked, why not leave it as is? And if you get an error, you'll have to debug it. We're here to help you get to a solution, but it requires some effort from your side as well. Please do some debugging and find out what's wrong.

Comment: i am trying to debug now......